# Java desktop application can not run from folder that has Russian name

Tags: java, internationalization, derby

I have created desktop application on netbeans using Java DB. It gets connection when user runs it, and it is working fine on all computers, but when I copy it to folder that has Russian name, I mean folder name is in Russian language, so the path to my program will include Russian characteristics obviously, it does not run, specifically it runs but can not make connection to Derby, my splash appears for less than a second and programs shuts down. What can I do? Please help.

Comment: We need more info here.. maybe you can screen-copy some stuff?

Comment: Are you interacting with the folder at all yourself? Otherwise it's going to be a JVM/sandboxing issue

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess -  sounds like a connection string encoding issue. This might be worth taking a look at.

From http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/tools/tools-single.html

> derby.ui.codeset
>
> Function Set this property to a supported character
>   encoding value when using one of the Derby tools with a language not
>   supported by your default system. Syntax
>
> derby.ui.codeset=derbyval
>
> where derbyval is a supported character encoding value, for example,
>   UTF8 (see Sample Character Encodings). Example The following command
>   line specifies to run ij using the Japanese territory
>   (territory=ja_JP) using Japanese Latin Kanji mixed encoding
>   (codeset=Cp939):
>
> java -Dderby.ui.territory=ja_JP -Dderby.ui.codeset=Cp939
>   -Dij.protocol=jdbc:derby: org.apache.derby.tools.ij
>
> The following table contains a sampling of character encodings
>   supported by the IBM Application Developer Kit. To see the full list,
>   go to http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html.
>   Table 2. Sample Character Encodings